# Store filter state for returning later

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with an index view and a show view, nothing special. The index view has filter options. What I want is that the filter options a user choses are stored in some way, so when a user opens the details screen and returns later, the same filtered records are shown.

The back button is not an option, because there can be done more than just opening the details screen and returning. I could add the filter params to every request made afterwards until returning to the index page, but that seems to be a bit cumbersome. What are my options?

Comment: session or local storage are good candidates

Comment: any examples you know of to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in the controller by creating a private method called `manage_filter_state`. This method is called in the index action, just before retrieving all records based on the value of the filter params. The mothod looks like this:

```
  private

  def manage_filter_state
    if params[:company]
      cookies[:company] = { value: params[:company], expires: 1.day.from_now }
    else
      if cookies[:company]
        params[:company] = cookies[:company]
      end
    end
  end
```

Basically, if the param value is set, it sets a cookie for keeping state. When visiting the page again later with another value of the param, it overwrites the cookie. Visiting later without a param value, it sets the param with the cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

There is normally no need to use a cookie for it. Store it in an session[ :name ]

A good place is inside a controller. To generalize the problem you could store anything QUERY inside a session variable and append when receiving a link.

Then reset when leaving a controller.